# What is this ResponseEntity?

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on an API using Swagger and I've been trying to figure out what ResponseEntity is, and how it works, and why use ResponseEntity?

When I run the API, and go to localhost:8080/suspect-api/swagger-ui.html. I am able to input the suspect ID, and the brand and call the getSuspect method.

In english, what does it do in the background and what is the purpose of ResponseEntity ?

Please see the code below:

```
public ResponseEntity<Suspects> getSuspects(@ApiParam(value = "Brand", required = true) @PathVariable String brand,
                                                @ApiParam(value = "ID", required = true) @PathVariable Long suspectId,
                                                Pageable page, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {
    return service.getSuspects(brand, suspectId, page, assembler);
}
```

I'm used to methods returning a particular type like String, int, boolean or even custom java objects like Student.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but I think it finally clicked.

ResponseEntity where T is any type, is just wrapping 'T' with a HTTP code.

For example, if you created a simple spring boot application and it has a method to retrieve employees:

```
public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(...) {
     // implementation here
}
```